# Support for Java as a language in executescript processor in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

ExecuteScript processor supports many languages as of now, Python;Groovy;clojure;Lua etc.
Why does it not allow me to write some custom code in java?

Comment: in `groovy` you can write like in java... ihmo. and if you want a pure java write your custom processor in java.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, we could add a Java "scripting engine" based on Janino but it has quite a few limitations that make it less attractive than just using Groovy. There are some differences between Groovy and Java (array initialization, and until Groovy 3, Java lambdas), but as the other folks said, it's pretty close.

Having said that, once NiFi requires Java 9+, I'm going to look into adding Java as a scripting language using the JShell REPL stuff in Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Java is not a "scripting" language. You can read more about enabling scripting language access to the JVM in [JSR-223](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223). As daggett pointed out, you can write code in pure Java and select the *Groovy* option, and this will compile the code to the same JVM bytecode.